# Error while trying to execute .robot file(Robot framework) from my python script

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

```
rc_out = robot.run('Coverage_Waive.robot', name='Coverage_Waive', log=None, report=None, stdout=stdout,
                               outputdir='./Log')
```

Above is the code I am trying to execute.

Getting the following error.

`module 'robot' has no attribute 'run'`

I was thinking it might be an issue with my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to check the code in the console (ptpython for convenience) and if this work for me should work for you too.

```
>>> import robot
>>> dir(robot)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'conf', 'errors', 'get_version', 'htmldata', 'libraries', 'model', 'output', 'parsing', 'rebot', 'rebot_cli', 'reporting', 'result', 'run', 'run_cli', 'running', 'sys', 'utils', 'variables', 'version', 'warnings']

>>> import os
>>> file = os.getcwd() + '/Tests/Example.robot'

>>> f = open(file, "r")
>>> f.readlines()
['*** Settings ***\n', 'Documentation    Example of TestSuite\n', 'Library    ${EXECDIR}/Settings/ExampleLibrary.py\n', '\n', '*** Variables ***\n', '${var1} =    ${EMPTY}\n', '\n', '\n', '*** Test Cases ***\n', 'Hello world\n', '    Log    Hello world\n', '\n', 'Using Custom Library\n', '    ${str}=    Hello World\n', '    Log    ${str}']
>>> f.close()

>>> robot.run(file, name='Example', log=None, report=None,  outputdir='./results')
==============================================================================
Example :: Example of TestSuite                                               
==============================================================================
Hello world                                                           | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using Custom Library                                                  | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example :: Example of TestSuite                                       | PASS |
2 tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /path/to/directory/results/output.xml
0
```